# Convert AJAX to non-AJAX call on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say if the server returns a 500 page on an Ajax call instead of the normal success content, I want to load that error page loaded as if it were a non-ajax call.

I don't want a redirect nor a reload because [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/) provides an excellent debugger that I'd like to use, but since the debug page is sent to the Ajax handler I don't know how to load that page.  I can't redirect to a generic page because then the error data won't be there, and I don't want to make a second call because they are POSTs which may have modified state, so a second call may not return the same stack trace/error as the first call.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
$( "body" ).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    $('html').html(jqxhr.responseText);
});
```

Which almost works, except that the Javascript of the page isn't loaded.

Comment: Would use of an `iframe` be acceptable?

Comment: @no.good Sure, I haven't actually worked with iframes since they seem to be frowned upon, but since this is just just for debugging I don't care.  Can you populate an iframe with page content stored in a javascript variable and have it load as if it were a normal page load? (i.e. all Javascript in the document.ready gets called, etc)

Comment: I posted an answer that show this working, using `document.write()` on the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [my solution using an iFrame](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/NKzuY/) - I'm loading the same page (on success but you could do it on error as well) and on load, the page will display an alert and log to the console to show that scripts in the response HTML work. I've tested this using FF4 and Chrome.

This is the core function (credit: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1021687)

```
function loadFrame(frameId, text){
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(frameId);
    ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
    ifrm.document.open();
    ifrm.document.write(text);
    ifrm.document.close();
}
```

- A disadvantage I can think of in using this method is that if the response HTML has frame-busting code or if it depends on the `window.location` value for some reason, this will likely fail.
- OTOH, the advantage in doing it using iframes over doing it using the `.html()` method as suggested by herostwist is that `.html()` uses the browser's native `innerHTML` property and so the behaviour becomes browser-specific; a browser may strip away `script` or `head` which will probably not help you debug. Additionally, if there are elements with the same id on the calling page and the response page, you might find that event handlers do not get attached to the response page's elements. But if these cases aren't applicable to your situation, this should be good enough too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery ajax documentation if you set the datatype to html "Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM." so your method should work if you force the datatype to html.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in the jsfiddle to me.  If it worked I'd expect to see the contents of the 404 page in the result, I only see the "start" div appear and disappear.